# How to convert word document into xml using a programming language

Tags: xml, dom, apache-poi

I was wondering how would one convert a word document into a xml document using a programming language.

So these steps: 
1: open word document
2: save file as .xml

I want a program to do that for me. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for all Microsoft documents, you can always access them in XML format using OpenXML. I converted Powerpoint Slide in XML, I am sure, you can convert Microsoft word as well. There is a tool OpenXML SDK, which can convert any microsoft document into XML using C#.

Comment: is it possible to do it in java?

Comment: @Wahla I think yes. I never tried though. Check it [here](https://poi.apache.org/oxml4j/)